# Grothendieck construction and coends

Tags: ct.category-theory, intuition, notation, limits-and-colimits, grothendieck-construction

In category theory, both the [Grothendieck construction](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/Grothendieck+construction) and [coends](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/end) are represented by a sort of "integral sign", respectively:
$$
\int F
$$
for a functor $F:C\to\mathbf{Cat}$,
and:
$$
\int^x G(x,x)
$$
for a bifunctor $G:C^{op}\times C \to D$.

Is it a conscious choice, that the two notations are similar? Is it because both resemble integration somehow? (I can see that for coends, but what about the Grothendieck construction?)

Or are they similar in some way? The only thing I see that they have in common is that both are "some kind of colimits", but is the analogy even stricter?

Comment: You can write the Grothendieck construction as a left Kan extension (left adjoint to the nerve $C \mapsto  Cat (A / (-), C) $. So it's a coend. And integration is a coend, while the end is a product integral.

Comment: See Example 4.22 [here](https://arxiv.org/abs/1501.02503); it's basically an expansion of what you find on the nLab page! :)